# invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')

Tags: c++

```
// RETURNS A RANDOM ELEMENT rho=[0,N-1] BASED ON FITNESS
int roulette_wheel(double fitness[], int N){
double f_sum=0.0, r, F, temp;
int k=0;
for (int j=0; j<N; N++) {
    f_sum=fitness[j];
}
r=rand()%f_sum+1.0; //(invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double'))
F=1.0/fitness[k];
while (F<r) {
    k++;
    F=F+1.0/fitness[k];
}

return k;
}
```

i don't know why that part says invalid operands... I thought my codes were right.

Comment: C does not support modulo operation on floating-point numbers. Use [`fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) for that.

Comment: can you please be more specific? my teacher gave the algorithm saying this " rand(0, f_sum)", so I translated it to that...

Comment: I can't be any more specific than that. C does not allow you to use `%` for performing the modulo operation on floating-point numbers, hence you have to use `fmod()` for this purpose. What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: sorry, I am a total beginner. I am using c++, I actually don't know "rand()" function, so I googled it. and if by floating-point numbers you meant 1.0, I changed it to 1, it doesn't help...

Comment: sorry, if you still don't understand what the problem is, then I can't help – you need to go back and learn the basics of C++.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, reiterating the comments above for clarity:
**You cannot use modulo on floating-point numbers.**

A function called fmod(), however, can give you the remainder of two floating point numbers.